# Webflux, reactor connection reset by peer unhandled

Tags: java, netty, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor-netty

So basically I am simulating a 'Connection reset by peer' locally using Toxiproxy or Wiremock (same behaviour for both of them) and I get the exception below.

The tricky part is that it will bypass any defined exception handlers and there's no way to revert the flow if there's a failure.

I tried configuring the WebClient as mentioned here: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/388 by either **removing the connection pool** or simply setting the HttpClient **keepAlive** property to **false**.

I defined a global exception handling mechanism by extending ErrorWebExceptionHandler but it doesn't go through.

Do you have any suggestions on how to manage this one? Or a proper configuration which I could try for either TcpClient / HttpClient or WebClient? What am I missing?
There must be a way to handle this properly..

```
[26/04/22 20:02:28] lvl=ERROR [ioEventLoopGroup-4-3]       r.n.r.PooledConnectionProvider - [id: 0xaf559a88, L:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:56755 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8989] Pooled connection observed an error
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:276)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:233)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:223)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:358)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:247)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1140)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:347)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:148)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:697)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:632)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:549)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:918)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
```

Comment: Please provide some code, how do you try to handle the exception